# malloc and pointers to pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, pointer-to-pointer

I'm trying to understand when I need to use malloc when using multiple levels of pointers. For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    typedef struct {
        char first[10];
        char last[10];
    } Person;

    Person *p;

    p = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    strcpy(p->first, "John");
    strcpy(p->last, "Doe");

    printf("First: %s Last:%s\n", p->first, p->last);

    return 0;
}
```

In this first version I'm using `Person *p` and I only use `malloc` to allocation space for type `Person`. In the 2nd version, I'll change `Person *p` to `Person **p`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    typedef struct {
        char first[10];
        char last[10];
    } Person;

    Person **p;

    *p = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    strcpy((*p)->first, "John");
    strcpy((*p)->last, "Doe");

    printf("First: %s Last:%s\n", (*p)->first, (*p)->last);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm still using only one `malloc` even though there is now another pointer.

In this third version, I'll use `Person ***p`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    typedef struct {
        char first[10];
        char last[10];
    } Person;

    Person ***p;

    *p = malloc(sizeof(void));
    **p = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    strcpy((**p)->first, "John");
    strcpy((**p)->last, "Doe");

    printf("First: %s Last:%s\n", (**p)->first, (**p)->last);

    return 0;
}
```

My questions:

1) Why do I need to `malloc` space for `**p` in the 3rd version, but I don't need to `malloc` space for `*p`? They are both pointers to pointers?

2) Also, why don't I need to `malloc` space for `p` in either the 2nd or 3rd version?

3) In the third version, what is the right size to `malloc` for `*p`? On my 64 bit Mac the `sizeof(void)` is 1, and the `sizeof(void*)` is 8, and both seem to work but what is the right one?

Comment: You *do* need to allocate `p` on v2. Your code is wrong.

Comment: v2 compiles and runs as expected for me.

Comment: Recompile with warnings enabled and you will find a few problems with your code.

Comment: You don't understand pointers. Do yourself a favor and *learn*.

Comment: the right one is void*. void* is a pointer which means its size is enough to contain every memory address in your 64 bit computer. It could be smaller if your computer was using a 32bit system.

Also Amit is right, your second version is wrong and you need to allocate memory for the first pointer (p). If you compile with warning flags (-Wall -Wextra) you'll get this :

`warning: ‘p’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   *p = malloc(sizeof(Person));`

Comment: I turned on the warnings and see what you are saying. So for v3, is the right thing to do `p = malloc(sizeof(void*)); *p = malloc(sizeof(void*)); **p = malloc(sizeof(Person));` or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Idr That's correct. Although it would be even better to use `malloc(sizeof(Person*));` instead of `malloc(sizeof(void*));`since you already know the type you're going to use. It doesn't change anything computer wise but makes the code clearer.

Comment: @ldr trial and error is not a good way to learn C, you can't tell whether your code is correct, or if it is broken but happening to produce the correct output this time

Comment: `*p = malloc(sizeof(void));` should fail to compile, you meant `sizeof (Person*)` or more simply `sizeof **p`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Dereferencing a pointer (`*p`) which had not been initialised provokes undefined behaviour in any case.
2. When allocating space to a pointer you mostly ever want to allocate to it memory with the size of what is it pointing to by typically using the `sizeof` operator. This latter case is the one and only exception to 1. that allows coding `*p`.

So the 3rd example could look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
        char first[10];
        char last[10];
} Person;

int main(void) {
    Person ***p;

    p = malloc(sizeof *p); 
    *p = malloc(sizeof **p);
    **p = malloc(sizeof ***p);
    strcpy((**p)->first, "John");
    strcpy((**p)->last, "Doe");

    printf("First: %s Last:%s\n", (**p)->first, (**p)->last);

    free(**p);
    free(*p);
    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really great demonstration of pointer-to-pointer-to-p... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm just going to put this here to summarize :

1) You do need to allocate space for `*p`. If you run your second program with valgrind, you'll see an error for alloc size (1 instead of 8); `*p` is a pointer to pointer, but `**p` isn't, it's a pointer to a structure.

2) You do need to allocate space in both cases and if you turn on the warnings (which you should never turn off anyway), you'll get this warning :

```
warning: ‘p’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized] *p = malloc(sizeof(Person));
```

3) The right one is `void*`. `void*` is a pointer which means its size is enough to contain every memory address in your 64 bit computer. It could be smaller if your computer was using a 32bit system. Although it would be even better to use

`malloc(sizeof(Person*));` instead of `malloc(sizeof(void*));`

Since you already know the type you're going to use. It doesn't change anything computer wise but makes the code clearer.